# How do I display varying pieces of data through a fixed template without making multiple slightly altered 'include' files?

Tags: php, html, mysql, xml

I have a database of different stores.

When a user clicks on a store name, I want an Ajax function to run displaying information about the store in a different div.

Information categories for all stores wll be the same: products carried, location, general information, etc.

I could easily make it so that each different store uses a different file name as an argument to the ajax function, and all files would have the same layout/format but with different data.

However i feel like this is bad form. How can i make it so that i have one fixed template and all that changes is the information specifics imputed into the template?

Please note that the store information display pages will also need to be able to have clickable links of their own (i.e. click on location and a google map pops up).

Is it something to do with XML? I dont know much about it.

Comment: if it's in a database, why not use the ID of the record the store's data is in? no need for different file names, just the ID of the store.

Comment: I'm lost as to what exactly your trying to do and what the problem is..?  On your ajax call just pass the store id to the script, the script queries the DB for that stores info and returns it back to the script to parse.

Comment: You are looking for a ''template engine'. That is a standard and normal design pattern. Try google for that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a template, return the data.

So it says `getstore.php?id=2` which returns a json string
`{"name":"my store", "info" :"blah"}`

Then you use java script to insert a new `div`, populated with that data.